# I Need Help Creating A Data Model Where Users Provide Required Documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making an application kind of like Uber where users would need certain documents before gaining access to the full functionality of the app. In the case of Uber, drivers need to provide a driver's license. However, in my application, the documents required vary depending on which city the user lives in.

The status of the documents can either be "verified" or "denied".

So my questions are:

Where should I store the status of those documents for each individual user?

and

How can I create a data model where I can specify which documents are required in each city?

Answer (score 1):

> *Where should I store the status of those documents for each individual user?*

- You can create a m:n mapping structure between User and Document and store the
  status inside this mapping structure

> *How can I create a data model where I can specify which documents are required in each city?*

- You can create a m:n mapping structure between City and Document. Add entries for each city and the needed documents inside this mapping structure